# Wrong position when zooming map in GoogleMaps (Android)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm implementing a map in Android Studio,but when I zooming the marker it goes to the wrong position.

[image: This image shows wrong position when zooming]

This is the maps class, that I create a canvas and after i tranform into bitmap:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;
    private Bitmap bm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bm = createImageRounded(getApplicationContext(), 80, 80, "S");
        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2093);
        MarkerOptions mrk = new MarkerOptions().title("Sydney");
        mrk.position(sydney);
        mrk.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm));
        mrk.anchor(0.5f, 1);

        mMap.addMarker(mrk);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }

    public static Bitmap createImageRounded(Context context, int width, int height, String name)
    {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(62, 176, 220));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        canvas.drawCircle(30, 30, 10, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats because you are drawing smaller image than marker bounds - you are creating `Bitmap` 80x80 dimen, but drawing on it smaller circle (10 radius, not centered, try `canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, Math.min(width, height)/2, paint);`)

also you are setting wrong [anchor](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#anchor(float,%20float)) (not centered, try to set `mrk.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);`)